# Why start a written sentence with 'Okay'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

On a forum, the sentence starting the discussion reads:

> Okay, I admit I'm a bit of a old puritan...but AIBU in thinking...school should not be promoting limo hire...

Is it just an unnecessary addition or does it affect the sentence at all?

Comment: "Okay" anticipates the objection that is articulated after it. "You're an old puritan, and so your opinion on school hiring is antiquated and idealistic."

Answer (score 3):

Using *okay* as a sentence adverb is an idiomatic way of setting up what follows.
As TFD Online notes, it is

> 8. (used to request or express agreement, acknowledgment, approval, etc.)

In the case you describe, it is used to acknowledge that what follows expresses a fault or deficiency: "Okay, I admit I'm an old puritan ..." This is a rhetorical flourish calculated to bring up a negative so that it may be dismissed, or at least diminished, in the mind of the audience.

It can also be used as a different kind of set up. Here it seeks to engage the audience's attention before relating an incident:

> Okay, so I'm in this bar and who walks in but my ex-wife—with my best friend!

Or here it is anticipating an objection:

> Okay, I know you're in a hurry, but let me tell you this one thing.